# How can I save Conversation History messages using EWS and have them appear correctly in the Conversation History Folder

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi, lync-2010

The Lync client Microsoft ships has an option to save conversation history into an exchange folder using EWS (Exchange Web Services) which is accessible through a c# managed API.  When Lync saves messages in the Conversation History folder using EWS, the messages appear as special conversation items.  This is accomplished by setting the ItemType to "IPM.Note.Microsoft.Conversation" -- at least in part.

My question is:  How do I get the complete behavior of the Lync-managed Conversation folder if I have to create the Conversation Folder myself rather than relying on Lync to create it?  I figured out that I need to set the FolderType to "IPF.Note.Microsoft.Conversation" but this is apparently not sufficient to get Conversation items contained in the folder to display correctly.  What other magic is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem turned out to be a failed integration between Exchange and Lync servers, which caused the outlook web access view of the conversation history folder to be rendered incorrectly.  The Conversation History Folder was in fact correct -- setting IPF.Note.Microsoft.Conversation was all that was required.

references:

1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000886
2. http://www.expta.com/2010/09/how-to-integrate-lync-server-2010-with.html
3. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398806.aspx
4. http://blog.schertz.name/2010/11/lync-and-exchange-im-integration/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Lync Console you can find 3 icons 1st Contacts, 2nd Activity Feesds , 3rd Conversations.
Click on 3rd icon  Conversations.
At bottom of the console you can find "View More in Outlook" Click on it and find all the conversation history folder in outlook.